# Seeking for advice about appropriate names

Tags: synonyms

I am writing an application (game) for teaching Maths. I have a problem how to name various objects. The first is clear - Formula (5-3=2). Then I want to have an object holding a definition how to generate set of formulas (generate 5 formulas with plus operator). And finally I need an object that will hold set of these definitions.

The definitions: Round, Test, Test Case
The set of definitions: Test, Test Set

What would native speaker choose?

Comment: No idea? When I play one set of formulas, how to name it? Round? Level? Circle? Set of questions?

Comment: Will the programmer be the only person to see these words?  Or will the user also see these words?

Comment: "Test", "[Test Case](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestCase)", and "[Test Suite](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestSuite)" all have technical meanings in computer programming.

Comment: Have you considered "Problem" and "[Problem Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_set)"?

Comment: Theoretically only developer will see these names. But when I will translate the game into English I will need to name them as well.

Comment: I feel a word problem to mean a trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what language you were coding in, as each language has different naming conventions.

However I would name the:

an object holding a definition how to generate set of formulas = **FormulasGenerator or FiveFormulasGenerator**

The other 4, I would call: **DefinitionRound, DefintionTest, DefinitionTestCase, DefinitionTestSet**

If I guessed wrong regarding what you are asking, please add a lengthier explanation regarding what you are trying to do.